# NVIDIA-SMI just shows one GPU instead of two

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have 2 GPUs, but my NVIDIA-SMI just shows me one. How can I make it recognize the other one?

[image]

Comment: nvidia-smi is a pain, are you with the newest drivers? I also strongly you to check the https://devtalk.nvidia.com forums

Comment: it could be a bad GPU, try swapping the cards or cables around to see if the problem follows a particular GPU

Answer (score 0):

I think GPU don't appears if is disabled. Check if "remove" file in your GPU device is empty. 
In your case, see next file;
  /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:83:00.0/remove

If this folder doesn't exists your device hasn't started correctly. In this case, If is possible for you, try checking that this GPU have enough power and is correctly connected.

If there is 1 in the file, change it by a 0 and reboot. If the folder exists but the file don't contains 
the value of 1 You can check other files in this folder for more information about the device because your device starts and some other things are causing the faulure. Check using other older driver version as says vfbsilva.

Font: I disabled some GPUs manually and the results are similar. https://labernia.wordpress.com/2017/07/16/gpu-testing/

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple GPUs using the following command.

For Query the GPU information

```
nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info
```

Add the Multiple GPU

```
nvidia-xconfig -a --device=Device0 --busid=[PCI Bus ID of GPU #0]
                                  --device=Device1 --busid=[PCI Bus ID of GPU #1]
```

Reboot the system to reflect the changes.